# ActionController::ParameterMissing in PinsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here's my error message:

> param is missing or the value is empty: pin

Extracted source (around line #45):

```
def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
end
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Please update your question with `form` code and `params` that are generated in the log

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: pin):
  app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:45:in `pin_params'
  app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:16:in `new'

Comment: Have you tried a search? There are hundreds of similar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ActionController%3A%3AParameterMissing

Comment: Yes, I've tried, sorry, I'm new to Rails so I'm missing something vital..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue happened because your `form` does not correct, inputs in your form must be named correctly to make sure `params` look like this

```
{
...
  pin: {
    description: "...",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!